# kubernetes traefik ssl passthrough

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, traefik

kubernetes: 1.25

traefik: 2.8.7

domain: gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk (I have already certificates for this domain)

kubectl get svc gitlab-ce -n gitlab -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: gitlab-ce
  name: gitlab-ce
  namespace: gitlab
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.98.93.9
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.98.93.9
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: port-1
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: port-2
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: gitlab-ce
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

so, I have a gitlab pod configured  with both http:

gitlab.rb I have  **external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk'**

here is the ingressroute

kubectl get ingressroute -n gitlab -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
  kind: IngressRoute
  metadata:
    name: gitlab-ingress
    namespace: gitlab
  spec:
    entryPoints:
    - websecure
    routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      priority: 1
      services:
      - name: gitlab-ce
        port: 80
    tls:
      secretName: gitlab-test-cert
```

With actual config, I can access the https://gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk

But, if I enable also https inside gitlab pod (gitlab will listen both 80 and 443)

**external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk'**

With the same ingressroute I get bad gateway...

So, my question is, once I have configured gitlab for both http/https how do I define traefik for ssl passthrough  ?

```
Something similar to  openshift:

oc create route passthrough route-passthrough-secured --service=frontend --port=80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the traefik for ssl passthrough , the gitlab should listen to the HTTP and HTTPs Ports. As per the question seems to be getting a bad gateway when you are running the same ingress route on HTTPS. Refer to this [HTTPS on Kubernetes Using Traefik Proxy](https://traefik.io/blog/https-on-kubernetes-using-traefik-proxy/) by Rahul Sharma and [Traefik Proxy 2.x and TLS 101](https://traefik.io/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/) by Gerald Croes .

To configure this SSL passthrough, you need to configure a TCP router by following this [traefik SSL termination doc](https://oracle.github.io/fmw-kubernetes/20.3.3/soa-domains/adminguide/configure-load-balancer/traefik/#create-ingressroutetcp) by oracle fusion middleware and modify your IngressRoute configuration so that Traefik can pass through SSL traffic to the backend GitLab service. Make sure `tls.passthrough is true`, this delegates the SSL termination to the backend and verifies the application whether you are able to access or not.

Comment: right, meantime I found also that I;d  have to use ingressroutetcp instead of ingressroute :) 

But, weird part .... 

   match: HostSNI(`*`) 

IF i would use HostSNI(`gitlab.mydomain-prod.dk`)  the redirection plain and simple wasn;t working....

Comment: can you share the error.